# Ububntu 13.10 x64 SWAP

Tags: partitioning, swap

I'm using ubuntu 13.10 64 bit. Established a system by default, compliance, sisema allocated to SWAP 35Gb file.
How to reduce size SWAP file?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

1. Start GParted in live Ubuntu session (if you need to make changes to your Ubuntu partitions; otherwise you could do it from the desktop session too),
2. Right click on swap partition and select *swapoff*,
   [image: snap1]
3. Shrink the swap to the size that you want. To do this, right click the swap partition and select *Resize/Move* option, and drag the slider left/right whichever seems appropriate *(also **make sure** the unallocated space should be in that side which would allow an easy merge with other partitions)*. And then click the <kbd>Resize/Move</kbd> button,
   [image: snap2]
   (it would have been easy if you included the partition layout that you have. If you're not sure about this step, you could edit your question to include a snapshot of partition layout or the output of the command `sudo fdisk -l`)
4. Then unmount (if they're mounted) the partition in which you plan to merge the unallocated space just created and again with *resize/move* option, extend the slider to cover up all the unallocated space,
5. After specifying such move and resize options, from the menu select *Edit -> Apply All Operations* or click the apply button in the toolbar. The resize and particularly move option will take a long time depending on the size of the files to be moved. So wait patiently.
   [image: snap4]